# How to make markers layers using gmaps api without using Google Fusion Tables

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How to make markers or polygon or polyline layers like in https://www.google.com/mymaps ?
like this one:
[image]

I have store marker in markers array and iterate over it to hide it on maps, but it is causing lag since it iterate at large number of markers. So I thought I should implement layers to my markers but dont know how to do it.

Any comment would be apreciated, event it is a reason why this question got down vote

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has same problem like above, I manage it to work by registering componen.setMap to dummy dom event listener 
so far its work very well (better than setting map by looping)
*sory for my bad english and thank you